# How do I change the small app icon for my app in the facebook developers console?

Tags: facebook

The UI for developers.facebook.com changed again and I was wondering where to find the option to change the small app icon. The 16 * 16 sized icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings are now located under **Products -> App Center**

(If that doesn’t show, then you need to add it first.)